# ionic2 build stopped after lint finished

Tags: ionic2, tslint

recently updated my ionic project beta 11 pro ionic rc0.
However, when the squeegee command
ionic serve
all scripts are executed but the project does not start.

```
D:\PROJETOS - GIT\mobile-rc1>ionic serve

Running 'serve:before' npm script before serve
> myawesomeapp@ watch D:\PROJETOS - GIT\mobile-rc1
> ionic-app-scripts watch
[10:24:04]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.36
[10:24:04]  watch started ...
[10:24:04]  build dev started ...
[10:24:04]  clean started ...
[10:24:04]  clean finished in 1 ms
[10:24:04]  copy started ...
[10:24:04]  transpile started ...
[10:24:04]  lint started ...
```

end here and not continue to next step

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to check from where or how this problem is coming:

```
npm run ionic:serve --verbose
```